# Cannot parse xml using JAXB if name contains -

Tags: jaxb

I am using JAXB annotations to parse a `test-results.xml` generated by testNG.

I can extract any attribute using `@XmlAttribute(name="someName")` but JAXB cannot read attributes with `-` (like `@XmlAttribute(name="some-name")`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The following is how you map to an XML attribute that contains a dash `-`.

```java
@XmlAttribute(name="some-name")
public String getSomeName() {
    return someName;
}

public void setSomeName(String someName) {
    this.someName = someName;
}
```